# WMSTileLayer is not updating after changing the layers parameter in react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to update my WMS layer on `react-leaflet v2.x.x`. The `WMSTileLayer` works only with the first layer and when I change the `layers` parameter on it, it shows the previously added layer. I have written following code,

```js
<MapContainer
              whenCreated={(mapInstance) => {
                mapRef.current = mapInstance;
              }}
              center={[38.861, 71.2761]}
              zoom={5}
              zoomControl={false}
              style={{ width: "100%", height: "70vh" }}
            >
              <ZoomControl position="topright" />
              <TileLayer
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                attribution="&copy; <a href='https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
              />

              <WMSTileLayer
                  layers={this.props.wmsLayer}
                  url={`${process.env.REACT_APP_GEOSERVER_URL}/wms`}
                  transparent={true}
                  format={"image/png"}
              />

            </MapContainer>
```

So my question is, how to update the WMSTileLayer when my `this.props.wmsLayer` is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `MapContainer` component, which makes me suspect you are actually using react-leaflet version 3.  In react-leaflet version 3, many [props are ***immutable***](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#props), meaning once they are set, changing them from a react props perspective will do nothing.  You would need to get a ref to the underlying L.TileLayer.WMS and call a method on it to change the layers.  Unfortunately, the leaflet docs do not seem to show any methods to do that (i.e. like a `setLayers` function or something like that).  You could call `setUrl` on the tilelayer, though I'm not sure that's what you want.

The easiest thing to do would be to add a `key` prop to your `WMSTileLayer`, and set it to some unique id that will force react to rerender when `this.props.wmsLayer` changes.  I'm not sure what `this.props.wmsLayer` is, but if it has some unique url or id associated with it, set `key={this.props.wmsLayer.id}` or whatever you can, and react will force rerender that component.  It's a bit overkill, but without some kind of `setLayers` function in the leaflet api, I'm not sure that there's a more proper way to do it.

Comment: Great!!! Thank you for the solution. Form your suggestion, I added the key as `this.props.wmsLayer` parameter to the `<WMSTileLayer` component and it solves the issue.